# How do I test link buttons with Mocha JS/WD/Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to automate testing in JS. I need to test a multi page form - so the application starts by filling in the first section, then clicks submit.

1) My application is such that I can't hit the second page without the first page - I store form data in the DB and just POSTing form data directly to the second page wouldn't work.

2) I have to check that based on the form input the application takes the user to the correct second page.

Is this possible with MochaJS and WD?

Comment: You may want to have a look to some E2E NodeJS tool for such task: there are many out there just google them.

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible. Just navigate to the first page, fill out the form, and assert on the url/page contents when you navigate to the 2nd page. What have you tried? It seems like you just need to review the documentation for these tools; the docs for WD.js have some basic examples that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for that! I had an error on the page which prevented the second page from loading during the test - and I thought I wasn't setting up the test properly. Your comment made me go back and check how the form was filled out and having corrected that I am able to check the correct section title on the second page.